# UNIX find : how to deal with paths containing spaces

Tags: shell, unix, path, find

I have a shell script with this line:

```
rm -rf `find something`
```

The problem is, if find returns a path with a space, `rm` of course interprets the space as a separator between two different paths and the command fails.

Is there a way to tell `find` to put quotes around the paths it returns or something else to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
find start_dir -name something -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -rf
```

Comment: How does the second one cope with spaces in paths?

Comment: It doesn't; it's missing the null-terminator for both `find` and `xargs` (which is easy to fix): `find start_dir -name something -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -rf`

Answer (score 4):

To be on the safer side you can use

```
$ find start_dir -print0 -name something | xargs --null rm -rf
```

to use the NUL (0) character as the separator between files.

Comment: `xargs --null` can also be written as `xargs -0`.

Comment: The `-print0` and `-0` options are a GNU extension, so on some systems you need to use `gfind` and `gxargs` instead of `find` and `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

`find something -exec rm {} \;`  but i am a little worried...

Answer (score 0):

A slightly faster way (replace "something" by whatever condition(s) you want) :

```
find something -exec rm -rf {} +
```